# A member variable's hashCode() value is different

Tags: java, multithreading

There's a piece of code that looks like this. The problem is that during bootup, 2 initialization takes place. (1) Some method does a reflection on `ForumRepository` & performs a newInstance() purely to invoke `#setCacheEngine`. (2) Another method following that invokes `#start()`. I am noticing that the hashCode of the `#cache` member variable is different sometimes in some weird scenarios. Since only 1 piece of code invokes `#setCacheEngine`, how can the hashCode change during runtime (I am assuming that a different instance will have a different hashCode). Is there a bug here somewhere ?

```
public class ForumRepository implements Cacheable
{
    private static CacheEngine cache;
    private static ForumRepository instance;

    public void setCacheEngine(CacheEngine engine) { cache = engine; }

    public synchronized static void start()
    {
        instance = new ForumRepository();
    }

    public synchronized static void addForum( ... )
    {
        cache.add( .. );
        System.out.println( cache.hashCode() );
        // snipped
    }

    public synchronized static void getForum( ... )
    {
        ... cache.get( .. );
        System.out.println( cache.hashCode() );
        // snipped
    }
}
```

The whole system is wired up & initialized in the `init` method of a servlet.
And the init() method looks like this conceptually:

```
// create an instance of the DefaultCacheEngine
cache = (CacheEngine)Class.forName( "com..DefaultCacheEngine" ).newInstance();
cache.init();

// init the ForumRepository's static member
Object o = Class.forName( "com.jforum....ForumRepository" ).newInstance();     
if( o instanceof Cacheable )
    ((Cacheable)o).setCacheEngine(cache);

// Now start the ForumRepository
ForumRepository.start();
```

**UPDATE** I didn't write this code. It is taken from [jforum](http://jforum.net/)

**UPDATE 2** Solution found. I added a separate comment below describing the cause of the problem. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Unless the `CacheEngine` is immutable, it seems pretty reasonable that it's `hashCode()` would change at runtime, depending on its contents.

Comment: The implementation of the CacheEngine does not implement hashCode().

Comment: @Jacques: does it inherit it straight from `Object`, or does it inherit an `@Override` from another superclass?

Comment: CacheEngine is an interface. And the implementation DefaultCacheEngine only implements the interface and does not have any superclass.

Comment: @Jacques: I would add some defensive feature in `setCacheEngine` that `throws IllegalStateException` if `cache` has already been previous set, just to make sure that it's not set again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to give WAY more information than this, but `CacheEngine` is probably a mutable data type, and worse, it may even be shared by others. Depending on how `CacheEngine` defines its `hashCode()`, this could very well lead to `aForumRepository` seeing various different hash codes from its `cache`.

It's perfectly fine for the same object, if it's mutable, to change its `hashCode()` over a period of time, as long as it's done in a consistent manner (which is another topic altogether).

#### See also

- [`Object.hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) -- make sure you understand the implications of the contract

---

#### On `cache` being `static`

More information has resurfaced, and we now know that the object in question, while mutable, does not `@Override hashCode()`. However, there seems to be a *serious* issue in design in making `cache` a `static` field of `ForumRepository` class, with a non-`static` "setter" `setCacheEngine` (which looks to be specified by `Cacheable`).

This means that there is only incarnation of `cache`, no matter how many `ForumRepository` instances are created! In a way, **all instances of** `ForumRepository` **are "sharing" the same** `cache`!

> [JLS 8.3.1.1 `static` Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.1)
>
> If a field is declared `static`, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A `static` field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized.

I think it's important to step back right now and ask these questions:

- Does `cache` need to be `static`? Is this intended?

  - Should instances of `ForumRepository` have their own `cache`?
  - ... or should they all "share" the same `cache`?
- How many instances of `ForumRepository` will be created?

  - Putting pros and cons of the design pattern aside, should `ForumRepository` be a singleton?
- How many times can `setCacheEngine` be called on a `ForumRepository` object?

  - Would it benefit from a defensive mechanism of throwing `IllegalStateException` if it's called more than once?

The best recommendations would depend on the answers to the above questions. The third bullet point is something that is immediately actionable, and would reveal if `setCacheEngine` is getting invoked multiple times. Even if they're only invoked once for each `ForumRepository` instance, it's still effectively a multiple "set" in the current state of affairss, since there's only one `cache`.

A `static` field with a non-`static` setter is a design decision that needs to be thoroughly reexamined.

Comment: Yes CacheEngine is mutable. It contains an internal HashMap.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as the best one mainly because you've given me ideas that have led to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the ForumRepository classes that you are comparing are the same. if you are doing newInstance you might have a weird classloader issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mutable objects with `hashCode` implementations based on mutable state are almost always a bad idea. For example, they behave very strangely in hash-based collections -- if you insert such an object into a `HashSet` and then mutate it, the `contains` method won't be able to find it anymore.

Objects that are naturally distinguished by their identity should not override `equals` and `hashCode` at all. If you override `hashCode` based on state, that state should be immutable. Examples are `String` and the boxing types. Those are often referred to as "value classes", because their identity has no significance -- it is meaningless to distinguish between multiple instances of `new Integer(42)`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that puzzles me about this question is this:

> Why are you looking at the hashcode of a CacheEngine instance?

It seems that your code is putting `Forum` objects into a cache and getting them back.  As such, it makes sense to look at the hashcode values for the `Forum` instances.  But the hashcode of the cache itself would appear to be entirely irrelevant.

Having said that, if the `DefaultCacheEngine` class inherits its implementation of `hashcode` from `java.lang.Object` then the value returned by the method is the "identity" hashcode, and this cannot change over the lifetime of an object.  If it does appear to change, this means that you are now looking at a *different instance* of the DefaultCacheEngine class.

Comment: I printed out a value in the cache in totally different methods and the contents was different (i.e. they were missing newly created items). So that's why I went down the path of suspecting that the CacheEngine instance is being mutated or reinitialized. It certainly could be other things.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem and I would like to share with you what I've learnt or discovered.

**Root cause of the bug**

The `jforum.war` webapp was being loaded twice by Tomcat 6.x, via two different virtual hosts. So yes, the `CacheEngine` was displaying two different hashCodes because they were loaded up in separate webapp classloaders.

**Solution**

The quick fix for me was to limit the invocation of the servlets in `jforum.war` via one specific virtual host address.